# how to carry performance testing on sticky enabled load balanced web application?

Tags: cookies, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

Hie,

I read a lot of blogs and tutorials. I cannot figure it out how to carry out performance testing on a cookie based sticky web application which sits behind a reverse proxy load balancer. I have 3 backed application servers serving same instance of a shopping cart. A load balancer sits infront of them and directs the traffic.

Problem: when i send HTTP request for performance analysis the load balancer (tracks client ip through cookie) redirects the HTTP request to the same back end server that was assigned to. I have an option of using IP spoofing but it wont work when the backend servers are distribted in WAN rather than LAN. Moreover, each backend servers has its own public IP address and sits behind the firewall.

Question: IS there a way Jmeter can be configured to load test in this scenario. or is there othere better solution

Much appreciate your thoughts and contribution.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Here are few possible workarounds:

1. Point different JMeter instances directly to different backend hosts bypassing the load balancer.
2. Use [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf) having JMeter nodes somewhere in the cloud, i.e. [Amazon Micro Instances are free](https://aws.amazon.com/free/). You can use [JMeter ec2 Script](https://github.com/oliverlloyd/jmeter-ec2) to simplify the installation, configuration and execution.
3. Try using [DNS Cache Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dns-cache-manager-right-way-test-load-balanced-apps), it enables individual DNS resolution for each JMeter thread.